# Jquery capture event on Textarea not working, but is on Textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am having problems understanding why code that I have developed is not registering a jQuery `Blur`/`OnBlur` event on a TextArea, but the same code is working for a Text input box.

This is within ASP.NET C#, but I have broken the problem down to its basic steps within a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/RdSme/

I have added a second textbox and textarea, just for testing:

```
<input id="TxtTest1" type="text" />TextBox Working
<p/> 

<textarea id="TxtTest2" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>TextArea Not Working
<p/> 
<input id="TxtTest3" type="text" /> Empty Textbox
<p/> 
<textarea id="TxtTest4" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea> Empty TextArea


$(function () {
    $('input[id*=TxtTest1]').bind("blur", function () {   
        var risks = {};
        risks.Source11 = $("[id*=TxtTest1]").val();
        alert("Step 1");    
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('input[id*=TxtTest2]').bind("blur", function () {   
        var risks = {};
        risks.Source11 = $("[id*=TxtTest2]").val();
        alert("Step 1");    
    });
});
```

Background. All input fields will send changes back to the database upon a user leaving the input box or making a change to a radio button or checkbox. The code works for a asp.net TextBox, even within a DataList. Ideally I need a "template" way of capturing changes made to inputs and then add on similar templates for radio buttons/checkboxes and dropdownlists.

Your help would be much appreciated

As a quick follow up question; what selector would be needed for a dropdownlist, checkbox and radiobutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selector` for the textarea is incorrect. Either use `:input` (http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) or keep it simple and use the element ID.

Try:

```
$(":input[id*='TxtTest2']").bind("blur", function () {
    var risks = {};
    risks.Source11 = $("[id*=TxtTest2]").val();
    alert("Step 2");
});
```

OR:

```
$("#TxtTest2").bind("blur", function () {
    var risks = {};
    risks.Source11 = $("[id*=TxtTest2]").val();
    alert("Step 2");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PTW66/1/

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you. As a quick follow up question; what selector would be needed for a dropdownlist, checkbox and radiobutton?

Comment: @Sam you can use `:input`. You will see this if you read the api docs link I provided in my answer. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ says `Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.`

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't targeting `textarea`.

You are just targeting `input` and not `textarea`.

You can simply do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('[id^=TxtTest]').bind("blur", function () {   
        alert("Step 1");    
    });
});
```

The above will select all.

In order to target a textarea you'll have to do `$('textarea[id*=TxtTest2]')`, which you can simplify into: `$('#TxtTest2')` as ids are unique.